# Multiple chatrooms on one page requires multiple channels or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable, rails-activejob

I am building message chatrooms part of the app and I was wondering do I need multiple channels. I am going to have specifically 4 chatrooms per URL.

Comment: If you have a single channel for all rooms, all messages from all rooms can be read in the browser console from any room. If your rooms need be private to authorized people who access a specific room, I suggest one channel per room is best.

Comment: Have a look at these chatrooms https://talkwithstranger.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not necessarily need 4 different actioncable channels. You can also send an identifier in the actioncable message and make sure your frontend processes it correctly.

Both architectures make sense, depending on whether your chatrooms have different goals or not.
If they are all the same, I would advise you to have only one channel so that you can refactor things like authentication, message transformations, etc.

Comment: Chatrooms are different:
-1st chatroom is used for communication between customer-staff
-2nd all staff members can communicate here
-3rd delivery guy and staff members are here
only thing in common between these chatrooms is that all of them will have same staff members present